# How to support multiple authentication scheme in Web API Core 2?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm developing a web api core 2.0 project.

I need support two authorization types: jwt and basic.

Inside my **ConfigureServices** method I've added this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer((options) =>
{
    options.Authority = $"...";
    options.Audience = "...";
});

services.AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddBasicAuthentication(credentials =>
Task.FromResult(
   credentials.username == "username"
   && credentials.password == "password"));
```

Inside my **Configure** method I've added this code:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

And finally I've added **AuthorizeAttribute** on my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MioController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Actually work only the last authentication specified on **ConfigureServices**.

How can I support both authentication types?
Thanks

*Note: I'm using this NuGet package for basic authentication [Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic).*

Comment: Authorize attribute has related property: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try Adding your authentication service in one chain

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer((options) =>
{
    options.Authority = $"...";
    options.Audience = "...";
})
.AddBasicAuthentication(credentials =>
{
    Task.FromResult(credentials.username == "username" && credentials.password == "password"));
}
```

and also on `AuthorizeAttribute` you can specify which Scheme you want to authenticate the request with

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + ", " + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: Hi Kahbazi, I've implemented your suggestions but now work only authorization with bearer (jwt).

Comment: You need to use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` for basicAuthentication to authenticate. By default only JWT would authenticate each request

Comment: Hi Kahbazi, using BasicAuthenticationScheme i obtain the same problem but with basic authentication.

Comment: I've resolved using [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + ", " + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]