# Allow windows and basic authentication in asp.net core web project

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am not sure if this is the way to go but here is what I am trying to achieve. I have two different types of controller action methods. And I need two different authentication method on each of them.

E.g. HomeController

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

ServiceController

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]
[Route("api/my-service")]
[ApiController]
public class ServiceController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("Evaluate")]
    [HttpPost]
    public EvaluateResponse Evaluate([FromBody]EvaluateRequest request)
    {
        //return something;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);
```

Startup.cs (Configure)

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Code for Basic authentication is implemented like mentioned [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/08/aspnet-core-21-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api).

Now, if I am trying to invoke `api/my-service/Evaluate` it's still invoking windows authentication.

How can I implement two different authentication technique, one for `HomeController` and another for `ServiceController`?

Comment: https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2018/03/20/using-multiple-authentication-authorization-providers-in-aspnet-core

Comment: @RyanWilson I went through that article already. I am not able to understand, how would I tell `HttpRequest` to bypass windows authentication, validate based on basic authentication if it is redirected to `ServiceController`?

Comment: You can specify different authentication schemes for different controllers.

Comment: @Shaggy This shows how to use both Jwt and Basic in the same project, it's an API project but it should still be able to show you what you need (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148648/how-to-support-multiple-authentication-scheme-in-web-api-core-2). I'm kind of confused by your architecture though, if your Service contains API's exposed to the outside world as you put it, why not make it it's own standalone entity, and call out to it from the web project?

Comment: Let's just assume I'd like to have windows authentication on one controller and basic authentication on another controller. I have updated my question with the required code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working, just needed to add following in `launchSettings.json` file

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not need to put windowsAuthentication for basic authentication

it should look like
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx",
"sslPort": xxxxx
}
}